# How to Create New List from Old List on every for loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Lets say I have a list with n elements like this -

```
problems = ["This is something", "This is something else", "This is 3rd element", "4", 8]
```

I want to make 1 list for every element in the given list like this -

```
List1 = ["This is something"]
List2 = ["This is something else"]
List3 = ["This is 3rd element"]
List4 = ["4"]
List5 = ["8"]
```

I was thinking of a code that uses a for loop to do this but I could not give the new list a name,

```
for i in problems:
   problems[i] = f"list{n}"
```

Is there any way I can do something like this ?

Comment: Also I cannot import any libraries

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Do **NOT** create variables dynamically. If this is for an assignment, tell your teacher this is a bad practice and you should not learn how to do this.

Comment: You should use dictionary for this purpose. But If you have a requirement to do this way then you can make use of globals().

Comment: You can create variables like this :
for idx, val in enumerate(problems):
    globals()[f"List{idx+1}"] = list(value0